# Binary search performance analysis

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-tree

Given that the leaves of comparison tree of a binary search algorithm are all on the same or adjacent levels, can we say that the comparisoms of keys done in searching a list of n item will be ceiling of `log(n)` plus 1 in the worst case, and be `log(n) + 1` in the average case?

I saw from a book that says it is approximately `log(n) + 1` in the worst and `log(n)` in the average, I think the worst case is fixed when n is given, so no need to give a approximate value, and the average should plus one.

The code is as following:

```
Error_code recursive_binary_1(const Ordered_list &the_list, const Key &target, int bottom, int top, int &position)
{
 Record data;
 if(bottom < top) {
   int mid = (bottom + top)/2;
   the_list.retrieve(mid, data);
   if(data < target)
     return recursive_binary_1(the_list, target, mid + 1, top, position);
   else
     return recursive_binary_1(the_list, target, bottom, mid, position);
  }
  else if(top < bottom)
    return not_present;
  else {
    position = bottom;
    the_list.retrieve(bottom, data);
    if(data == target) return success;
    else return not_present;
  }
}
```

Please correct me if I am not.

Comment: why do you think the average case should be `log(n)+1`?

Comment: @UmNyobe Because it is from `lg(2n)`, where 2n corresponds to n sucessful searches and n failure searches.

Comment: Could you please provide the specific binary search implementation you are refering to? I have seen several possible versions and the estimate for the comparisons is different.

Comment: @izomorphius yes, I should add the code first.

Comment: Note that those numbers only apply when you have a *balanced* binary tree.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, when the leaves are all on the bottom or adjacent levels of the tree.